# Entity Framework: Attaching an entity of type 'Country' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to simplify what is a much more complex data model, but for clarity let's assume I have two DB tables: `tb_Item` and `tb_Country` with an FK on the `tb_Item` table relating `tb_Country.CountryId` and `tb_Item.MarketId`.

In code, I have `Item` and `Country` classes, where `Country` is a member of `Item`, because I need to access some `Country` properties in the business logic (should not be relevant for this question though).

```
public class Item 
{
    public long ItemId { get; set; }
    public int? MarketId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I retrieve Item records from the DB to display in the UI, I do something like this (again, simplified):

```
using (var ctx = GetContext())
{
    var items = ctx.Items.Include(x => x.Country).AsQueryable();
}

var matching = Items.Where(d => d.AsOfDate == items.Where(d2 => 
d2.Country.IsoCountryCode == d.Country.IsoCountryCode && 
d2.AsOfDate <= asOfDate).Max(to2 => to2.AsOfDate));
```

Then, when I make any changes via the UI and save, this `Save` method is called:

```
public void SaveItems(IList<Item> items)
{
    _repo.ExecuteInTransaction(ctx =>
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var existingItems = _repo.FindItems(
                item.AsOfDate.Date,
                item.MarketId)
            var existing = existingItems.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AsOfDate.Date == item.AsOfDate.Date);
            var createNewForAmend = existing == null && item.ItemId > 0;
            if (createNewForAmend)
            {
                existing = _repo.GetItemById(item.ItemId);
                existing.ItemId = 0;
                existing.AutomaticTouchDisabled = true;
            }
            _repo.SaveItem(ctx, item);
            if (!createNewForAmend) continue;
            _repo.SaveItem(ctx, existing);
        }
    });
}
```

Where `FindItems` is:

```
public IList<Item> FindItems(DateTime asOfDate, int? countryId)
{
    using (var ctx = GetContext())
    {
        var rawItems = ctx.Items.Include(x => x.Country).AsQueryable();

        var items = rawItems.Where(d => d.AsOfDate == rawItems.Where(d2 =>
                                                                d2.Country.IsoCountryCode == d.Country.IsoCountryCode && 
                                                                d2.AsOfDate <= asOfDate).Max(to2 => to2.AsOfDate));

        if (countryId.HasValue)
            items = items.Where(d => d.Country.CountryId == countryId.Value);

        return items.ToList();
    }
}
```

...`GetItemById` is:

```
public Item GetItemById(long id)
{
    using (var ctx = GetContext())
    {
        return ctx.Items.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ItemId == id);
    }
}
```

...and `SaveItem` is:

```
public void SaveItem(Context ctx, Item item)
{
    ctx.Items.Attach(item);
    ctx.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    ctx.Items.AddOrUpdate(item);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

At the point where `ctx.SaveChanges()` is executed and I'm saving an Item record with a `CountryId` that already exists in the `Country` table, I get the dreaded EF error:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 'Attaching an entity of type 'MyService.Data.Model.Country' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.'

My question is, I don't expect to have uniqueness constraint issues on the `tb_Item` table for duplicate countries (I expect a many:one relationship for items to country). It's almost as if the code is trying to save a duplicate country record to the `tb_Country` table when saving a record to the `tb_Item` table.

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, I just can't figure out what it is...have tried the suggestions in other questions related to this: trying to detach the `Country` model, using `AsNoTracking()` when retrieving records, not doing the `.Include(x => x.Country)` when retrieving Item records, etc., but nothing quite works.

Comment: There can be multiple ways of why this is happening, but one thing obvious I see - why you calling AddOrUpdate after you already attached entity? This will just try to attach it again and should cause exception you see

Comment: Removing either the .Attach or the .AddOrUpdate lines doesn't make any difference, same error. If I remove .Attach and the .State lines, then I can see the SQL Server error: `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_tb_Country_Code'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tb_Country'.`

Comment: According to the error message you should this should not be happening when saving but when trying to attach the `item` to the context. Without more code it's hard to say why exactly this is happening, but the gist should be that you already have a country with (for instance) Id 1 attached somewhere (maybe because of a include call). Then you have another object reference also with Id 1 and also try to attach that one, causing the error.
Quick and dirty fix is to add the FK to the model and only set the CountryId. Otherwise check your code / EF calls and DbContext instance usage.

Comment: @Jejuni, by "add the FK to the model", do you mean decorating the Item.Country property with a `[ForeignKey("MarketId")]` attribute? Have tried that with no luck earlier.

Comment: Let's say I have 3 Items and 2 of them have the same child Country (of Id 1). I don't expect that to be an issue, since many items can have the same Country/one Country can belong to many Items. I wouldn't expect this to blow up. If I do a simple insert of an Item in raw SQL, I can add as many Item rows as I want with the same Country Id.

Comment: Rather than fiddling with the entity state multiple times, you should consider using `.TrackGraph` to decide how each reachable entity should be tracked. Perhaps adding a breakpoint to the call back so you can check how each object is attached. But since we can't see how your `, Item item` parameter has been constructed, we can't offer more specific help.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, unfortunately I'm not using EF Core for this, so don't have `.TrackGraph`. Let me try and add details on how `Item` is constructed, quite a bit of business logic to obfuscate.

Comment: Just added more details on how exactly I retrieve and save `Items`.